# Create an histogram with raw mysql data on grafana

Tags: histogram, grafana

I need to create an histogram, using data from a mysql database, in grafana. I have a 0 or 1 data, that means 1 if the bus is been charging, or 0 if it is not.

[image: Data that I have.]

I need to create a histogram by hour of the day, for the amount of time that i ask in the timebar of grafana.

[image: Histogram to create]

I hope any idea, of help to how to build this.

Thanks :)

Comment: The title of this first graph in English is "weekly hourly distribution of charger use". I wonder how this database looks like, and some sample data.

Comment: can u also share your sql query?

Comment: i think you are better of reading this: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/getting-started/getting-started/